# Matrix diagonalization example

Tags: matrices, applications

I want a real world example or simply a good example that explains the use of a diagonal matrix, and when to prefer to use a diagonal matrix?

any other important information about diagonal matrix or matrix diagonalization.

why in the world one would want to diagonalize a matrix?

Comment: Half of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631670/what-is-the-motivation-defining-matrix-similarity) question is related to yours. My answer in particular gives one example of why diagonalization is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fibonacci-sequence has been solved using diagonalization.

$1,1,2,3,5,8, \ldots$.

Starting with $\left(1,1 \right)^T$, the next number in the sequence is given by the last entry of

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

where the vector $\left(a,b \right)^T$ contains the previous two numbers of the sequence.
Note that the last entry of the previous vector becomes the new first entry.
Now, clearly, you can repeat this procedure to find the $n+2$-th number of the sequence by calculating

\begin{align*} 
& \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^n \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= A^n \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

This is where diagnoalization comes into play. If you diagonalize $A$, i.e. $A = P D P^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal, it is easily seen that

\begin{align*}
&A^n \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
& = P D^n P^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

$D^n$ is calculated easily just by raising each diagonal entry to the power of $n$.

You can determine $P$ and $D$ explicitly to derive a formula for the $n+2$-th number in the sequence.

Note that you can replace the starting vector $(1,1)^T$ by any vector of your choice.

Comment: thanks for the time to answer, I can see it's useful, but I can not understand the example (my brain is too humble in mathematics)

Comment: can you supply another example in coordinate systems or something

Comment: Did you know that it is not nice to have other people writing out entire proofs and not even giving them an upvote in return ?

Comment: believe me I have tried but I didn't have enough reputation points to vote you up