# Why is it useful to know when a linear operator on a vector space is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, linear-transformations

I'm currently taking a conceptual course in linear algebra, and I'm trying to understand why it would be theoretically useful or illuminating to know when a linear operator (or its matrix representation) is diagonalizable. Why is this? How does it help us to more deeply understand vector spaces, linear operators, their applications, etc.?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the motivation defining Matrix Similarity?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631670/what-is-the-motivation-defining-matrix-similarity).

Comment: Diagonalizable matrices are very convenient to work with computationally. If you can write $A = P D P^{-1}$, the powers of $A$ can be evaluated very quickly.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23312/what-is-the-importance-of-eigenvalues-eigenvectors